# How to make text flow onto other div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox. I am trying to make the text 'healthy meals' line up with food delivery. However the only problem is it is in two seperate divs.

I want my code to look like this.

[image]

I currently have this:

[image]

so my guess is that I need to make the text spill over to the next div. Anyone know how to do this?

Here is my code.

```css
.mainheader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(./img/hero.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.mainheader>div:first-child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>omnifoods</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="mainheader">
    <div class="slogan">
      <h1>GoodBye Junk Food. <br> Hello Super Healthy Meals.</h1>
      <div class="butt">
        <button style="margin-right: 20px;">I'm hungry</button>
        <button>Show me more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div>Food Delivery</div>
      <div>How it works</div>
      <div>Our cities</div>
      <div>Sign up</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `white-space: nowrap` to `h1` tag as follows and it will prevent the word break.

```css
.mainheader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(./img/hero.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.mainheader>div:first-child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>omnifoods</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="mainheader">
    <div class="slogan">
      <h1 style="white-space: nowrap;">GoodBye Junk Food. <br> Hello Super Healthy Meals.</h1>
      <div class="butt">
        <button style="margin-right: 20px;">I'm hungry</button>
        <button>Show me more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div>Food Delivery</div>
      <div>How it works</div>
      <div>Our cities</div>
      <div>Sign up</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it only works when I resize the screen however when it is in full screen it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add `margin-left: auto; margin-right: -80px` on `h1` tag. You can adjust how much the title will be indented using `margin-right` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

add this to your slogan or h1 wherever you want.
this might help you :)